# How do I enable UEFI secure boot for a linux build made with yocto?

Tags: linux, uefi, yocto, secure-boot, systemd-boot

I'm producing a yocto build, and want to enable UEFI Secure Boot on the intel machine I'm using.  This is a pretty basic yocto build, using core-image-minimal and meta-intel.  The artifacts it produces look like:

```
./core-image-minimal-intel-corei7-64.wic
./bzImage-intel-corei7-64.bin
./bzImage--6.1.38+git0+d62bfbd59e_11e606448a-r0-intel-corei7-64-20240208204456.bin
./core-image-minimal-intel-corei7-64.manifest
./OvmfPkKek1.crt
./OvmfPkKek1.pem
./systemd-bootx64.efi
./core-image-minimal-intel-corei7-64-20240215181510.rootfs.tar.xz
./microcode.cpio
./modules-intel-corei7-64.tgz
./core-image-minimal-intel-corei7-64-20240215181510.rootfs.manifest
./microcode_20230808.cpio
./modules--6.1.38+git0+d62bfbd59e_11e606448a-r0-intel-corei7-64-20240208204456.tgz
./bzImage
./core-image-minimal-intel-corei7-64-20240215181510.testdata.json
./grub-efi-bootx64.efi
./ovmf.vars.qcow2
./core-image-minimal-intel-corei7-64.qemuboot.conf
./ovmf.secboot.code.qcow2
./linuxx64.efi.stub
./OvmfPkKek1.key
./ovmf.secboot.qcow2
./core-image-minimal-intel-corei7-64.tar.xz
./core-image-minimal-intel-corei7-64-20240215181510.rootfs.wic
./ovmf.code.qcow2
./core-image-minimal.env
./core-image-minimal-systemd-bootdisk-microcode.wks
./ovmf.qcow2
./core-image-minimal-intel-corei7-64-20240215181510.qemuboot.conf
./core-image-minimal-intel-corei7-64.testdata.json
```

My boot partition looks like:

```
./loader
./loader/loader.conf
./loader/entries
./loader/entries/boot.conf
./EFI
./EFI/BOOT
./EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi
./bzImage
```

I can't figure out how to enable secure boot using these files.  There's an option to enroll a signature, and when I do that using the bootx64.efi file, and then try and boot, I get some sort of bzImage error, and then something about a security policy violation.

I get similar (but different) errors when I try and do the same process on a random Kali linux install off of a USB drive.

There are also uefi options like "enroll signature", "enroll PK", "enroll KEK", etc., and I tried these hoping to be able to select those OvmfPkKek1* files yocto is producing, assuming those are the keys, but they don't show up on disk when browsing my boot partition via the uefi interface, even though I copied them over.  I'm not sure why.

Any ideas how I make this install work with secure boot?

Comment: In a physical system, the active Secure Boot keys are not stored as files on disk, but as variables in the system's UEFI NVRAM. For a virtual machine, there is usually a file that is used by the virtualization host to store the UEFI NVRAM variables of a particular VM. Maybe the `ovmf.vars.qcow2` or `ovmf.secboot.qcow2` is supposed to be that file? However, some KVM Secure Boot documents would suggest using a `*.fd` suffix for such files instead of `*.qcow2`, as the firmware variable files are not really QCOW2 files.

Comment: I'm not using a VM.  I'm installing on a machine's sata drive at /dev/sda.  I only have the keys on disk for now so that the UEFI could find them, but they aren't showing up in the UEFI, even though the directory structure (/EFI, /loader) is.  Maybe the UEFI is expecting some particular filename or extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clearing the PK (Primary Key) before trying to input other keys. This should place Secure Boot into *Setup Mode* in which there should be minimal restrictions on key updates. After updating any other Secure Boot key variables to suit your needs, input your key as the PK to return Secure Boot to normal mode.

Primarily, you'll want your key in the `db` key variable, since it's the whitelist: unless specifically blacklisted, any `*.efi` signed with a key that's in the whitelist variable will be allowed to execute by Secure Boot.

The `dbx` key variable is the blacklist: when loading any file signed with a blacklisted key, or whose hash matches a blacklisted hash, the firmware will stop it from loading and/or won't allow it to execute.

The `KEK` key variable controls (programmatical?) updates to the `db` and `dbx` while Secure Boot is in normal mode. If possible, you'll want your key in this variable too.

The `PK` variable controls updates to the KEK variable, and holds only one key - ideally yours, instead of the system manufacturer's default key.

Your `OvmfPkKek1.pem` is probably the file needed by UEFI, but there are several possible formats it might expect.

If the firmware cannot read a PEM file (either as-is or with a `*.cer` or `*.crt` suffix), try converting it into a DER format:

```
openssl x509 -in OvmfPkKek1.pem -inform PEM -out OvmfPkKek1.cer -outform DER
```

The suffix of the DER file might have to be either `*.cer` or `*.crt`.

Some UEFI user interfaces expect specifically *EFI Signature List* files (`*.esl`), which you can generate using the `efisiglist` command, that can probably be found in a package `pesign`, or the `cert-to-efi-sig-list` command from package `efitools`.

To convert a DER-format certificate into an EFI Signature List:

```
efisiglist --outfile OvmfPkKek1.esl --add --certificate=OvmfPkKek1.cer
```

or

```
cert-to-efi-sig-list OvmfPkKek1.cer OvmfPkKek1.esl
```

While not in Secure Boot Setup Mode (i.e. while PK is set), it's possible the firmware user interface will only accept ESL files *signed with a Secure Boot key whose certificate is in KEK or PK key variable*. This follows the same rules as when updating the Secure Boot keys programmatically from a running operating system. If so, the expected file suffix for those could be `*.auth`.

The `sign-efi-sig-list` command in the `efitools` package can generate `*.auth` files from `*.esl`s. Note that you'll have to create a separate `*.auth` file for each key variable, even if you use the same actual key:

```
sign-efi-sig-list -a -c OvmfPkKek1.pem -k OvmfPkKek1.key db OvmfPkKek1.esl signed-key-for-db.auth
sign-efi-sig-list -a -c OvmfPkKek1.pem -k OvmfPkKek1.key KEK OvmfPkKek1.esl signed-key-for-KEK.auth
sign-efi-sig-list -a -c OvmfPkKek1.pem -k OvmfPkKek1.key PK OvmfPkKek1.esl signed-key-for-PK.auth
```

Comment: Marking this as the solution as my primary problem ended up being that the UEFI wanted the cert in DER format.